# When does the Yoast SEO filter hook wpseo_sitemap_urlimages fire?

Tags: plugin-wp-seo-yoast, sitemap

I am trying to attach a simple function to the Yoast SEO filter hook `wpseo_sitemap_urlimages` and get the function to run, but I cannot do so.  My code is:

```
function tp_filter_wpseo_sitemap_urlimages($images, $post_id) {
    error_log("test message");
    return $images;
}
add_filter('wpseo_sitemap_urlimages', 'tp_filter_wpseo_sitemap_urlimages');
```

To get this function to run, I have tried opening the following Yoast XML sitemaps:

- sitemap index (https://example.com/sitemap_index.xml)
- post sitemap (http://example.com/post-sitemap.xml)
- page sitemap (http://example.com/page-sitemap.xml)

My eventual goal with this is to add additional images to the Yoast post and page sitemaps (per [these Yoast instructions](https://kb.yoast.com/kb/images-in-the-xml-sitemap/)).

The only support Yoast has offered for this is to direct me to [this page](http://hookr.io/filters/wpseo_sitemap_urlimages/).

Comment: IIRC the sitemaps are cached in wp_options, that‘s why you might not immediately see anything on the frontend

Comment: @swissspidy Thanks for that.  But I'm not asking why nothing appears on the front-end.  But shouldn't the hook still fire? I'm asking why the hook isn't firing at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I wanted to say in my previous comment:

This hook is only fired when the sitemap is being **built**. After that, it's **cached** and always served from cache. That means you'll never see any change on the frontend because it's all cached.

To disable the cache you can use the following code during development:

```
add_filter( 'wpseo_enable_xml_sitemap_transient_caching', '__return_false' );
```

After that, the sitemap is never served from cache but always built when viewing the sitemap in the frontend. Then you'll see some changes.

Comment: OK thanks.  That should work.  Let me give that a try--I'll need a few days.  In the meantime though, instead of disabling the cache, is there a way to tell Yoast to explicitly re-build the sitemap?

Comment: OK thanks for that.  I added the cache disabling code, re-loaded the post sitemap page, and then my hook fired as expected.  For the future though, how did you know the sitemap was cached, and how did you know that the caching could be disabled?  Is there any documentation that describes this behavior?  Or was asking here my only recourse?

Comment: I had to extend the sitemap once for a project and had the same struggle as you. Then I just looked at the code to see how things work :-) Haven't looked for docs, so I don't know if there's a way to force a re-build (besides deleting the entries from the database) as disabling the cache was enough for me.

Comment: Ah yes, looking at the code--hadn't thought about doing that, but I guess I should give that a shot if I'm out of options.  Thanks for all.

Comment: It's a shame that this does not just have a lower cache timeout value so that it would renew every couple of days or so...